# Using WooCommerce Points and Rewards as Payment Method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

so I've been building a points system in my WordPress website, and everything up until this point seems to be working fine, except for the final and most important step.
I wanted the accumulated points to be used to purchase specific products, such as Dokan Subscription or Product Promotion...etc.
I've been trying to create a custom Payment Gateway that would use the points as a means of payment, but for some reason, it doesn't show in the checkout page.
It does show in the WooCommerce settings and it's enabled.
_price_in_points meta is another field I added to the Product where I can set the price for it in points instead of the monetary value.
What seems to be the issue? Why it doesn't show during the checkout ?

```php
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    return;
}

function initialize_points_gateway() {
    
class WC_Gateway_Points extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id                 = 'points';
        $this->method_title       = __( 'Points', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->method_description = __( 'Allows payments with user\'s points.', 'woocommerce' );
        

        $this->init_form_fields();
        $this->init_settings();

        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    }

    public function init_form_fields() {
        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled' => array(
                'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'label'   => __( 'Enable Points Payment', 'woocommerce' ),
                'default' => 'no'
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
                'default'     => __( 'Points Payment', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
            'product_ids' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Product IDs', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => __( 'Comma separated list of product IDs that can be bought with points. Leave blank to allow all.', 'woocommerce' ),
                'default'     => '',
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
        );
    }

public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Check if WC_Points_Rewards_Manager class exists
    if (!class_exists('WC_Points_Rewards_Manager')) {
        wc_add_notice( 'Points system is currently unavailable', 'error' );
        return;
    }

    $points_needed = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_price_in_points', true );

    // Check if _price_in_points meta key is set
    if (!$points_needed) {
        wc_add_notice( 'Unable to determine the number of points needed for this order', 'error' );
        return;
    }

    $user_points = WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::get_users_points( $user->ID );

    if ( $user_points < $points_needed ) {
        wc_add_notice( 'Not enough points', 'error' );
        return array('result' => 'failure');
    }

    WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::decrease_points( $user->ID, $points_needed, 'points_payment', $order->get_id() );

    $order->update_status('completed');
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    return array(
        'result'   => 'success',
        'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
    );
}
}

function add_points_gateway_class( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Points'; 
    return $methods;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_points_gateway_class' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'initialize_points_gateway' );
```